# How do I program a button to display the length of an array? (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, button

```
<button onclick="lengthArray()">Item Quantity</button>
<p id="quant"></p>
```

```
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Graphics Card","Cooling Fan"];
function lengthArray() {
    products.length();
    document.getElementById("quant").innerHTML = products.length();
}
```

Hello!
I need some programming a button in javascript that can display the length of the array when the button has been clicked. The code above is my failed attempted to tackle this task, as nothing happens when the said button is clicked.
Edit: Thank you guys for helping me out !

Comment: There is no button!

Comment: `length` its a property no a function, So use it like `.innerHTML = products.length;`

Comment: `length` is not a functions.

Comment: just remove "( )" from length as everyone said

Answer (score 2):

Use `products.length` instead of `products.length()` for getting length of array

```js
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Graphics Card","Cooling Fan"];
function lengthArray() {
    document.getElementById("quant").innerHTML = products.length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="lengthArray()">Item Quantity</button>
<p id="quant"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! Any way i can also add a line of text saying "Length:" before the displayed length or is that too much extra lines of coding?

Comment: `"Length: "+products.length`

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
function lengthArray() {
     document.getElementById("quant").innerHTML = products.length; <<-- Remove "()"
}
```

Because length isn't a function. it's a property :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="lengthArray()">Item Quantity</button>
<p id="quant"></p>


var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Graphics Card","Cooling Fan"];
function lengthArray() {
    document.getElementById("quant").innerHTML = products.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the brackets after length -
to get the length of an array you have to use `length` not `length()`

this is how your code should look like

```
document.getElementById("quant").innerHTML = products.length;
```

and add a button to run the function

```
<button onclick="lengthArray()">Button</button>
```

or you could just use your paragraph by adding a text to click on

```
<p id="quant" onclick="lengthArray()">now visible</p>
```

---

hope it helps ! ^^

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Graphics Card", "Cooling Fan"];

function lengthArray() {
  console.log(products.length);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="lengthArray()">Item Quantity</button>
<p id="quant"></p>
```